# Condition on Equality of closure of open ball and closed ball, suppose I have a counterexample

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Also for $x \in X$ and $r \ge 0$ define:
$$
 B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) < r \} \quad \mbox{ and } \quad
 K(x,r) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) \le r \}.
$$
Denote by $\mbox{cl}(U)$ the closure of some set in the topology induced by $d : X \times X \to \mathbb R$. Then we have

i) $\mbox{cl}(B(x,r)) \subseteq K(x,r)$

ii) if $X$ is normed, then we have $\mbox{cl}(B(x,r)) = K(x,r)$.

This fact is from an authoritative source, guess must people know it? (if not, I can give proof and reference too).

I think I have found a counterexample, so I am a little bit confused.

**Counterexample 1:** Let $2^{\mathbb N}$ be the set of all one-sided infinite $0$-$1$-sequences. For $\xi = (\xi_i) \in 2^{\mathbb N}$ define
$$
 || \xi || := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \xi_i.
$$
Then $(2^{\mathbb N}, ||\cdot ||)$ is a normed space over $\mathbb F_2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$ (the finite field with two elements). Therefore it is also a metric space, with metric
$$
 d(\xi,\eta) = ||\xi - \eta|| = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\xi_i - \eta_i) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} d'(\xi_i, \eta_i)
$$
where $d'(0,0) = d(1,1) = 0, d(0,1) = d(1,0) = 1$ (by the way, this is the discrete metric
on $\{0,1\}$), but this inclusion is proper, so both sets are not equal, despite the fact that the space is normed?

Let $\xi = 00000000\ldots$ we have
\begin{align*}
 B(\xi, 1/4) & = \{ \eta  : d(\xi, \eta) < 1/4 \} \\
             & = \{ \eta = (\eta_i) : \eta_1 = 0, \eta_2 = 0 \} \setminus \{ 001111\ldots \}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 K(\xi, 1/4) & = \{ \eta : d(\xi, \eta) \le 1/4 \} \\
             & = \{ \eta = (\eta_i) : \eta_1 = \eta_2 = 0 \} \cup \{ 010000\ldots \}
\end{align*}
We have
$$
 \mbox{cl}(B(\xi,1/4)) = \{ \eta = (\eta_i) : \eta_1 = \eta_2 = 0 \}
$$
and so $\mbox{cl}(B(\xi,1/4)) \subseteq K(\xi, 1/4)$, but $\mbox{cl}((B(\xi,1/4)) \ne K(\xi, 1/4)$.

What went wrong here?

Comment: Probably only $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces (possibly also $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces) were considered. For vector spaces over a general field with a valuation, it can be that the norm defines an ultrametric, and then the open balls are closed, so generally $B(x,r) = \operatorname{cl} B(x,r) \neq K(x,r)$ then.

Comment: Comment by Tim Carson, posted as an answer: "Are you sure (ii) doesn't have requirements on the base field? For example, its proof here

http://math.stackexchange.com/a/262394/ 

does."

Comment: You wrote: *I can give a reference, too.* I think you should. (And considering the comments you have received so far, you should also check whether this reference has some assumptions on the field $\mathbb K$ you are working with.)