# Closure of an open ball is equal to the closed ball (Euclidean space)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Consider the Metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|)$. Show that $Cl(B(x,r))=C(x,r)$ with $C(x,r)$ the closed ball around $x\in X$ with radius $r$.

$\operatorname{Cl}(B(x,r))\subseteq C(x,r)$ is trivially true (the closure is the smallest closed set containing $B(x,r)$).

I, however, have difficulties proving it the other way around. I am able to prove it when I introduce the concept of a boundary point and show that $\operatorname{Cl}(B(x,r))=B(x,r) \cup \partial(B(x,r))$, but the concept of a boundary hasn't been introduced yet in the lectures. Can anyone give me a hint on how to prove this without using the concept of a boundary?

> Definition: Let $x\in X$. We say $x$ is a closure point of $A\subseteq X$ when $\forall r>0$ $B(x,r)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. We denote the set of all closure points as $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$

Comment: This can be solved using http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108017/259262 .

Comment: What definition(s) of "closed" have been introduced in your lectures?

Comment: $A\subset X$ is closed when $A^c$ is open. $A\subset X$ is called open when $\forall r>0$ s.t. $B(x,r)\subset A$.