# Boundary of any Open Ball

Tags: general-topology

> Is it true that for any open ball $B(x;r)$, its boundary must be the sphere, $S(x;r)=\{y \in X : d(x,y)=r\}$?

So I am trying to go about this with initial intuition.  Since an open ball is defined by $d(x,y)<r$, it must be that the closure is indeed going to be the points on the sphere, but this doesn't seem too convincing to me.

Are my thoughts correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the discrete topology, then every set is open and closed and so the boundary is the empty set.

Edit: You can define a metric $ d(x,y) = 1 $ if $x\neq y$ and $ d(x,y) = 0 $ if $ x = y $. So if $ (X,d) $ is a metric space, then you can show that every set is open and closed. Thus $ U \subset X$ is open so the boundary is in $ X - U $ and likewise $ X - U $ is open so the boundary is in $ U $ but $ (X - U) \cap U = \emptyset $. So the boundary must be the empty set.

Comment: I haven't touched what an actual topology is yet, I've only been given definition of open and closed sets (and definitions that follow from this). So my question is, what is an example of a 'discrete topology'?

Answer (score 1):

Infimum is right with their counterexample, but let me offer non-trivial insight.

---

The *boundary* of an open ball $O \subseteq S$ is precisely $\overline{O} - O$. Why? From Wikipedia, the boundary of a set $S$ is..

> *...the set of points in the closure of S, not belonging to the interior of S.*

Since $O$ is open, its interior points are exactly $O$, and so $\overline O - O$ is the boundary of $O$.

You have asked when it is the case that: 
\begin{align}
\partial B(x;r) &= \{y \in M : d(x,y) = r\} \\
&= \{y \in M : d(x,y) \leq r\} - \{y \in M : d(x,y) < r\} \\
&= B_{closed}(x;r) - B(x;r) \\
\overline{B(x;r)} - B(x;r) &= B_{closed}(x;r) - B(x;r)
\end{align}

It is obvious that both $\overline{B(x;r)}$ and $B_{closed}(x;r)$ contain the entirity of $B(x;r)$, so we may reduce this to:
$$\boxed{\overline{B(x;r)} = B_{closed}(x;r)} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \partial B(x;r) = \{y \in M : d(x,y) = r\}$$

**Knowing this, your question becomes equivalent to the following:**

> *When is it the case that the closure of an open ball is equal to the
>   closed ball?*

...which is [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108017/139270) with the following equivalent condition:

> For any two distinct points $x,y$ in the space and any positive $\epsilon$, there is a point $z$ within $\epsilon$ of $y$, and closer to $x$ than $y$ is. 
>   That is, for every $x\neq y$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is $z$ with $d(z,y)<\epsilon$ and $d(x,z)<d(x,y)$.