# Open and Closed Balls in Perfect Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A perfect metric space is defined as one where $M=M'$, where $M$ is the space itself and $M'$ is the set of all cluster points of $M$, that is, points whose $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods contain infinitely many elements of $M$.

I think that it is sufficient for a space to be perfect for the closure of each open ball to equal the corresponding closed ball.

Is it necessary though? Looking at [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108010/when-is-the-closure-of-an-open-ball-equal-to-the-closed-ball), it seems like the accepted answer has a weaker necessary condition than perfectness, but I'm not certain.

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}$, consider $d(x,y) = \min \{ 1, \lvert x-y\rvert\}$.

Comment: This metric space is perfect, isn't it? Each $\epsilon$-ball will contain infinitely many points.
But I don't think the closure of an open $1$-ball is the closed $1$-ball with same centre......so sufficiency may not hold either.

Comment: Now I wonder whether I parsed your second paragraph as you intended it. Did you mean "closure property implies perfect" or "perfect implies closure property"?

Comment: @DanielFischer I meant to ask whether closure property implies perfect. But now looking at your first comment, I don't think sufficiency holds, whereas I have written the opposite in the question. Which in turn could mean that the condition in the other answer is in fact stronger, not weaker.

Comment: It does, except for spaces containing only one point. If there are at least two points, "For any two distinct points $x,y$ in the space, and any positive $\epsilon$, there is a point $z$ within $\epsilon$ of $y$, and [something that implies $z \neq y$]" tells you that $y$ is a cluster point. Since $y$ is arbitrary, the space is perfect. The empty space is perfect too. But singleton spaces aren't perfect, yet they have the closure property (trivially).

Comment: Okay so fundamentally, I seem to have things the other way around. Closure property implies perfect (for non-singleton spaces), and perfection is weaker than the property mentioned in the linked proof. Thank you! (maybe you could put this in an answer?) @DanielFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space being perfect or not depends only on the topology of the space, while the closure property (the closure of the open ball $B_r(x) = \{ y : d(x,y) < r\}$ is the closed ball $K_r(x) = \{ y : d(x,y) \leqslant r\}$ for all $r \in (0,+\infty)$ and all $x \in X$) clearly depends on the metric. On every metric space $(X,d)$ with at least two points we can find an equivalent metric (i.e. a metric $d'$ inducing the same topology as $d$) such that there is at least one open ball $B_r(x)$ whose closure is a proper subset of $K_r(x)$. A uniform construction works. There always is a point $x_0 \in X$ and a $c > 0$ such that $B_c(x_0)$ is not dense in $X$, and there is a $y \in X$ with $d(x_0,y) = c$. Then taking $d'(x,y) = \min \{ c, d(x,y)\}$ works.

Hence a perfect metric space need not have the closure property.

Conversely, the closure property implies that the space is perfect if the space is not a singleton space.

This is vacuously true for the empty space. If the space contains more than one point, choose an arbitrary $x \in X$, and $y \in X \setminus \{x\}$. Let $r = d(x,y)$. Then by the closure property $x \in \overline{B_r(y)}$, hence for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $B_r(y) \cap B_{\varepsilon}(x) \neq \varnothing$. Since $x \notin B_r(y)$ it follows that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \setminus \{x\} \neq \varnothing$. Hence $x \in X'$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $X$ is perfect.

Singleton spaces aren't perfect, but they trivially have the closure property.