# Sphere disjoint with closure of its open ball

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space, and define

- the sphere $S(x_0,r)\colon= \{x| \rho(x,x_0)=r\}$, and
- the (open) ball $B(x_0,r)\colon=\{x|\rho(x,x_0)<r\}$.

Also denote

- the interior $\mathop{Int} A$ the (inclusion-wise) greatest open set contained in $A$,
- the closure $\mathop {Cl}A $ the (inclusion-wise) smallest closed set containing $A$, and
- the boundary $\mathop{Fr}A \colon= \mathop{Cl}A\setminus \mathop{Int}A$.

How can the sphere be disjoint with the closure of the open ball with the same radius and centre
$$ S(x_0|r) \cap \mathop{Cl} B(x_0,r) = \emptyset ?$$
Does a sphere contain the closure of the open ball with same centre and radius?

Comment: See related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108010/when-is-the-closure-of-an-open-ball-equal-to-the-closed-ball) for the standard example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the set $\mathbb{N}$ with the regular metric $d$ on the reals. then
$$B(5,2)=\{4,5,6\} \text{ and }Cl\left(B(5,2)\right)=\{4,5,6\}$$
and
$$S(5,2)=\{3,7\}$$